# How to Retrieve Shared Preferences in Same Activity, It comes Empty?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, retrofit2

In my application's login screen, i am fetching a *JSON* response into the shared preferences in my retrofit2 **onResponse** method. I get everything as **correct** from the **database** and putting as correctly into the **shared** **preferences**. I am getting an **User_Role** from db as string, then based on User_Role, i am directing the user to according activity. **I need to reach that User_Role in case R.id.Login:** step. In my Logcat i see my response is as i want. I check with Toast after i commit preferences, if i can manage to put preferences correctly. Yes it is writes to screen response.success Organizator. So the only problem i can not retrieve it. Please help.

Because of everything works correctly in my apicall(because i checked every step with *Toast.makeText.show();* on screen)  i am only putting my LoginActivity.class code below,

LoginActivity.class :

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button bSignUp, bLogin;
    EditText etPassword, etEmail;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    Intent intent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        bSignUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSignUp);
        bLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogin);
        bSignUp.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
        bLogin.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
        etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
        etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Logging in");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait ....");

        bLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {

            case R.id.bSignUp:
                Intent SignUpIntent = new Intent(this, SignUpActivity.class);
                startActivity(SignUpIntent);
                break;

            case R.id.bLogin:

                String email = etEmail.getText().toString();
                String password = etPassword.getText().toString();
                if (!email.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()) {
                    progressDialog.show();
                    loginProcess(email, password);

    //Here i need to obtain SharedPreferences that i filled in onResponse Method. It goes directly wrong email or password statement. Because of can't retrieve settings.getString("User_Role","")

                        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("Pref", MODE_PRIVATE);
                        String userRole = settings.getString("User_Role","");
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, userRole, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        if (userRole.equals("Organizator")) {
                            intent = new Intent(this, OrganizerHomeActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);

                        } else if(userRole.equals("Speaker") || userRole.equals("Listener")) {
                            intent = new Intent(this, UserHomeActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        else{
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Wrong email or password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Fields are empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
        }
    }

    private void loginProcess(String email, String password) {
        LoginAPI loginAPI = RetrofitService.getClient().create(LoginAPI.class);
        retrofit2.Call<UserList> call = loginAPI.loginUser(email,password);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<UserList>(){
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<UserList> call, Response<UserList> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    List<User> userLists = response.body().getUser();
                    SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                    //SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("Pref", MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = settings.edit();
                    prefEditor.putBoolean(Constants.IS_LOGGED_IN, true);
                    prefEditor.putString("UserName", userLists.get(0).getFirstName());
                    prefEditor.putString("SSN", userLists.get(0).getsSN());
                    prefEditor.putString("User_Role", userLists.get(0).getUserRole());
                    prefEditor.commit();
                    // In my Logcat i see my respnse is as i want, and i check with below Toast if i can manage to put preferences correctly. Yes it is writes to screen response.success Organizator. So there is no problem.
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "response.success  "+settings.getString("User_Role",""), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<UserList> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your SharedPreference logic after onResponse success. it's because it executes before your response get. that's why it empty. so Change code like this

```
private void checkMethod(){

                    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("Pref", MODE_PRIVATE);
                    String userRole = settings.getString("User_Role","");
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, userRole, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    if (userRole.equals("Organizator")) {
                        intent = new Intent(this, OrganizerHomeActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    } else if(userRole.equals("Speaker") || userRole.equals("Listener")) {
                        intent = new Intent(this, UserHomeActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Wrong email or password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Fields are empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
}
```

And Call this method from onResponse like below

```
public void onResponse(Call<UserList> call, Response<UserList> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                List<User> userLists = response.body().getUser();
                SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                //SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("Pref", MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = settings.edit();
                prefEditor.putBoolean(Constants.IS_LOGGED_IN, true);
                prefEditor.putString("UserName", userLists.get(0).getFirstName());
                prefEditor.putString("SSN", userLists.get(0).getsSN());
                prefEditor.putString("User_Role", userLists.get(0).getUserRole());
                prefEditor.commit();
                // In my Logcat i see my respnse is as i want, and i check with below Toast if i can manage to put preferences correctly. Yes it is writes to screen response.success Organizator. So there is no problem.
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "response.success  "+settings.getString("User_Role",""), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                checkMethod();
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Try to start intent condition in the response method. No need to store value in shared preferences.

Comment: but later, i will use these preferences also, thanks for advice.